# Running .net application next to asp core app on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, module

I am trying to get my code to run alongside, in process, with an asp core web site.
With .net framework there is an option to create a module. Then, in order to "inject" that module so that it is run when the site runs all I need to do is add the module to web.config or launch it from a .cs file from \app_code.

With asp core, there is a concept called middleware but in order to add a middleware, the user has to write it into their startup code.

I need a way to run my .net core code when the site has started (first page accessed) without requiring the user to change their code to do so. Changing config files after deploy is OK but not compiled files.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What .net application are you trying to run? If its a .net web application. You can host it as sub-application and run application initalization.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Comment: @jokiesding it's an interesting option and I'll try to play with it but it ends up running two processes. I am looking for a way to run in process with the web application.

Comment: As long as you share same app pool for the application, there would be only one process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 options here:

1. [Hosting startup assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

> An IHostingStartup (hosting startup) implementation adds enhancements
> to an app at startup **from an external assembly**. For example, an
> external library can use a hosting startup implementation to provide
> additional configuration providers or services to an app.

2. [IIS modules with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/modules?view=aspnetcore-3.1) - you may still be able to inject your module in case you run the app on IIS. Add a web.config manually into the root directory and configure your module in there.

Comment: The hosting startup assemblies was exactly what I was looking for.
1. It's run without changing the original user code
2. It can easily be deployed onto an existing web application
In addition, it is supported from .net core 2.1.